# How to pass a 2D matrix to function

Tags: c++

I am doing an addition of matrices using classes.I have declared a class 'Matrix'.now i need to pass an object of Matrix to a function.how do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the best way (IMHO) is to overload `operator+()`. Thus in your code, you'll need to use only `+`:

```
class Matrix {
    private:
        // Your code
    public:
        // Your code
        friend Matrix operator+(const Matrix &c1, const Matrix &c2);
}

friend Matrix operator+(const Matrix &c1, const Matrix &c2) { <--- passing by reference
    // Your code to add matrices
}

int main() {
    Matrix A, B;
    Matrix C = A + B;
}
```

In the case of the passing by value `Matrix sum(Matrix a, Matrix b)`, you will need to write a copy constructor if memory for matrix is allocated dynamically.

Passing by pointer `Matrix sum(Matrix *a, Matrix *b)` is a C style coding, so it is still correct, but not preferable for C++.

Answer (score 0):

```
Matrix object;
// ...
f(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a few ways to do it.

By Value:

```
void func (Matrix m);
```

By Reference:

```
void func (Matrix& m);
```

Or By Pointer:

```
void func (Matrix* m);
```

Which one you use depends on your needs and semantics of the operation.